# Return JWT token to javascript SPA from oauth login

Tags: laravel, cordova, oauth, vue.js, jwt

I'm developing a javascript spa in vue.js which is going to eventually be a cordova application. As well as a backend api built with lumen.

I'm trying to provide login with facebook and google functionality. I've added the laravel socialite package and created a redirect and callback route. Ive created a page in my spa with the login buttons that direct to my api redirect. The user is redirected to facebook's oauth mechanism I login, the callback routes handle function looks something like this

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
  $oauthUser = $this->socialiteManager->with($provider)->stateless()->user();

  $userEntity = $this->repository->findOrCreateOauthUser($oauthUser);

  $providerEntity = app()
    ->make('em')
    ->getRepository('Entities\Social\Provider')
    ->findOneBy(['name' => $provider]);

  if(is_null($providerEntity))
  {
    throw new \Exception('Oauth Provider not found');
  }

  $socialAccountEntity = app()
    ->make('em')
    ->getRepository('Entities\Social\SocialAccount')
    ->findOrCreateSocialAccount($providerEntity, $oauthUser, $userEntity);  

  $token = $this->auth->fromUser($userEntity);

  $resource = $this->item($token)
      ->transformWith($this->transformer)
      ->serializeWith(new ArraySerialization())
      ->toArray();

  return $this->showResponse($resource);
}
```

It basically gets a the oauth user, finds or stores them in the database, finds or stores their social account info,

```
$token = $this->auth->fromUser($userEntity);
```

Then authenticates them with JWT issuing a token. Which is then serialised and returned as a json response.

The problem is that the response is given while on the backend application, im never returned back to the javascript SPA.

Instead of returning json I could do some redirect like

```
return redirect()->to('/some-spa-callback-route');
```

But should the api be aware of the SPA location? and how will this work when the SPA is ported into cordova, as the mobile application wont have a url?

My thoughts are that A

The social provider should redirect directly to the SPA at which point it should make another request exchanging the authorisation code for a JWT token.

B it redirects to the SPA with a query string containing the token, which doesn't sound secure.

or c sends some type of cookie back.

And I am still confused as to how to actually redirect from my api to a mobile application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I ended up with the following login flow

User is directed to Oauth provider
Oauth provider returns an access token to the client
the client sends the access token to my api
my api sends a renew request to the Oauth provider
the Oauth provider validates the token and returns a new one to my api
my api exchanges the access token for a jwt token
my api returns the jwt token to the client

In my opinion it is the only correct way to authenticate SPA applications, and it is important to renew the Oauth token the client provides rather than blindly exchanging for a jwt as you can't trust the client, and is better than issuing redirects from the api that isn't very restfull

Comment: I don't think it's necessary or beneficial to renew the access token. You mention not trusting the client, but that's exactly the purpose of the token exchange and the fact that the access token has a short life. By renewing the access token, wouldn't it just mean you are making the request live longer and thus increasing security risks?

Comment: thanks. I had exact same problem. For some reason, there is no tutorial on the Internet, describing this process from A to Z.

Comment: @user618509, i am using same tech stack as yours.
i managed to get the access_token after the social authentication. but the question is. how did you send the access_token to your clients?

i am using laravel/passport not jwt tho.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with 2 services, your spa should talk to a single auth service in your backend. You register your service as the oauth callback and you handle oauth/jwt as you described. Your auth service can also be the decision point for user (re-)authentication. Since your frontend calls your backend directly, you can now return the json payload back to your web/mobile caller.

Comment: this doesnt solve the issue on how to direct the user back to the SPA when your at the api callback